# Intersection of subspaces with sets!

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, projective-geometry, projective-space, affine-geometry

Does anyone have any references about intersections of subspaces with sets (which are NOT subspaces)?

Intersection of subspaces is boring, but if I am given a set $S$ which is not a subspace and some list of subspaces $\mathcal{E}$, what do we known about the $E\in \mathcal{E}$ when $E$ is intersecting $S$.

Any reference would be really helpfull.

**UPDATE:**

If I have an $n$-dim vector space $V$ over $GF(2)$ and a set $T$ with $|T|\geq \frac{|V|}{2}$, which is NOT a subspace, is there a bound on the number of $k$-dim subspaces $U$ of $V$ intersecting $T$.

Comment: I would suspect that your question is to general to get a useful answer?

Comment: @copper.hat I assume so too. It is weird that after all this time no one asked this question, I can't find any references. Give me a set of vectors, at most how many subspaces are going through it. I don't ask for equality, give me a bound

Comment: A set of vectors defines a subspace $S$ and if it has codimension at least 2 it is not hard to see that there are an infinite number of subspaces that contain $S$ properly.

Comment: @copper.hat But if I am considering subsets of an n dimensional subspace over GF(2) which have more than half of the elements. How many subspaces of dimension m would intersect it.

Comment: You need to update your question to make it more specific.